# Getting error when trying to deploy spring boot + mysql app to AWS using codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, aws-codepipeline

I have build a cicd pipeline using AWS codepipeline.
Source is coming from Github which successed. Build is also successed.

I am using Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2 as a platform in Elastic Beanstalk as Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux shows as it's being deprecated.

I'm getting error during deployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

```
Action execution failed
Deployment completed, but with errors: Failed to deploy application. Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-03b7a9c8a86ffde8e'. Aborting the operation. [Instance: i-03b7a9c8a86ffde8e] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error.. Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
```

I checked eb-engine.log file and see below error message.

```
...
...
2021/11/07 05:01:18.765214 [INFO] extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /tmp/extracted_app_source_bundle
2021/11/07 05:01:18.765227 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /tmp/extracted_app_source_bundle
2021/11/07 05:01:19.122461 [INFO] finished extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /tmp/extracted_app_source_bundle successfully
2021/11/07 05:01:19.122560 [INFO] app source bundle is zip file ...
2021/11/07 05:01:19.122566 [INFO] extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/
2021/11/07 05:01:19.122578 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/staging/
2021/11/07 05:01:19.498171 [INFO] finished extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/ successfully
2021/11/07 05:01:19.498694 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPreBuildHooks
2021/11/07 05:01:19.498712 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/prebuild/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...
2021/11/07 05:01:19.498717 [INFO] Executing instruction: Java Specific Build Application
2021/11/07 05:01:19.498724 [INFO] no buildfile found, skip building java application
2021/11/07 05:01:19.498731 [INFO] old env file for build tasks does not exist
2021/11/07 05:01:19.498742 [INFO] Executing instruction: CheckProcfileForJavaApplication
2021/11/07 05:01:19.498776 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [CheckProcfileForJavaApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: there is no Procfile and no .jar file at root level of your source bundle 
 
2021/11/07 05:01:19.498786 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2021/11/07 05:01:19.498869 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1636261279,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}
...
...
```

Below is my buildspec.yml file.

```
version: 0.2
 
phases:
install:
runtime-versions:
java: corretto11
commands:
- echo install
pre_build:
commands:
- echo pre_build
build:
commands:
- mvn package
- echo build
post_build:
commands:
- echo post_build
 
artifacts:
files:
- target/course_reviews_backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

PLEASE HELP!!

Any help would be appericated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am facing the same issue. I get this error when my source comes from CodeBuild, but it works fine when built locally and uploaded. The folders appear identical.

Comment: [EDITED]

Adding this configuration in the buildspec.yml file solved the issue for me.

'discard-paths: yes' 

When "discard-paths" is set to "yes", the file paths are discarded, and only the file names are kept. This means that the files in the "target" directory (in my case, the "course_reviews_backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" file) is copied to the specified S3 bucket without their original directory structure.

Comment: I solved my issue which was different. In my POM file, I was zipping a deployment folder and passing that up to CodeDeploy in buildspec. The run time, Beanstalk, had an issue with the zip file for some reason (no errors or logs pointed to it). Skipping the zip and specifying the unzipped deployment folder as the artifact corrected the issue.